# How best to display a mass of values in a view but if each doesn't have a value for it not to take up page space

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view

I've tried

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Overall) %> 
<%: Model.Overall %>
```

and neither work and may only ideas right now would be to make if statments on the view itself that if it was null not to display but I have over 200 values so time consuming and wasteful, my other idea was to do the same but in jquery document.ready the if statements.

does anybody have any simple ideas or css solutions which would prevent a mass of white space.

thx

Comment: Turns out I was being a fool and hadn't realised that on the page I had been adding in <br /> next to each displayfor and so thats what took up the space but since the answer here might prove useful to other's I'll mark the 1 I think is most useful as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MVC 3 using display templates you can create a loop over the properties.  So similar to another answer, create a display template for NotEmptyProperties.ascx and in your page call:

```
<%: Html.DisplayForModel("NotEmptyProperties") %>
```

And then in the display template:

```
foreach(var p in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    if(ViewData.Eval(p.PropertyName) != null)
    {
        <%: Html.Display(p.PropertyName) %>
    }
}
```

The `Eval` method on the `ViewDataDictionary` will let you null check the properties in your loop and only display the ones that aren't null.

Comment: To control the order you can use the DisplayAttribute on your Model, if you don't mind invoking each property manually you can either use a UIHint or write a custom HTML Helper.

Comment: Some of this looks like it would be easy for me to screw up and fail to get it to work so for now I'm gona try mateuscb approach before I try yours but since both seem very useful and exactly what I'm looking for then I'm gona +1 both.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use custom [Display Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html). It would leave your view very clean, and your if/else clause in one location. Your displaly templates would look something like this (CheckEmpty.ascx):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<String>" %>
<%= String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model) ? String.Empty : Model %>
```

Then you have two options of where to specify the Display Template, In your view:

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Overall, "CheckEmpty") %>
```

or using data annotations in your model:

```
 //model
 [UIHint("CheckEmpty")]
 String Overall {get; set;}

 <%-- View --%>
 <%-- Don't need to specify template, since UIHint already specifies --%>
 <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Overall) %>
```

Comment: I think he didn't want to invoke each property manually, I suggested a similar solution that would loop the properties for him automatically and employ something similar.

Comment: I'd confused myself when I 1st looked at this but I think I'd probably choose the 2nd option to cut down on code in my view which is already getting very large, I'll try it out now and comment on how it turns out.

Comment: Oh also I wonder if there are any extra "using System.(...)" in the model for this to work?

Comment: @myzifer you should only need `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. Also, if your view is getting too big, you should look into [`Html.RenderAction` and `Html.RenderPartial`](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/11/24/renderpartial-vs-renderaction.aspx), they could help out.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried something like below :

```
<% if(Model != null) { %>

    <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Overall) %> 

<% } %>
```

Comment: wouldn't this only apply if the whole model was null or not? Since it will always have data in it then if that is the case this wouldn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @Myzifer Sorry but your question is not so clear to me. Make your expectations a little bit more clear, then I might be able to provide more solution.

Comment: I was asking if your answer would affect the model as a whole which is what it seems to indicate? As stated in my question title I need to base it on a value by value basis so it will assess each and every value and only take up page space should that value actually have any data. I thought I had been clear about that but sometimes my written english can let me down.